# How to colour white bit of a half tone filter effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, filter, halftone

I created a half tone over an image using the filter effect. I want to change the white in the half tone to a creamy brown/white colour. How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one simple method you could use, although there are probably many ways to do it.

1. Create a layer under the image layer, and fill with a creamy colour.
2. Set the image layer mode to Multiply

[image]